# How can I debug an app that works in the simulator, but not on actual devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, ios-simulator

I'm working on an app and there is a bug that happens only on devices; in the simulator everything seems to go smoothly. I already asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258573/playing-many-different-videos-on-iphone-using-avplayer) with the exact issue and some code, but in case that doesn't produce any results I would like to learn more about how I can go about debugging (and fixing) this *sort* of problem.

Comment: This is not really a question.

Comment: Never trust a simulator.

Comment: Ok, the questions are. Have you ever had an app working in iOS simulator but not an actual device? if so, how did you work it out?

Comment: Case sensitivity. The device is case sensitive, the simulator is not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing many different videos on iphone using AVPlayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258573/playing-many-different-videos-on-iphone-using-avplayer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it works for a bit and then stops suggests some kind of resource bottleneck.

Perhaps there is a memory leak, perhaps you are not freeing all the resources that you allocated when switching from one video stream to another?

You can track your resource utilization to see if this in fact could be the issue.

Comment: It was indeed resource related, it was due to a memory leak, it's been taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

Simulator runs code as x86, whereas the device runs it as ARM.  Sometimes compiling won't give the same output for both, but that should only apply if you're getting into some *really* low-level stuff.  Another concern is that performance is going to be vastly different between devices - the iPad 2 might run apps faster natively than a MacBook Air, which in turn will run apps faster than an iPhone 1.  If you're doing anything that's resource-intensive, testing on a device is definitely the way to go.  Also, testing on the *worst* device you can is best... if it'll run on the first iPhone, it'll run on *any* iPhone.  Other things you can't test on the simulator are the accelerometer, gyro, etc (despite the fact that all Macs have a built-in 3-axis accelerometer...)

What kind of bug is your problem?  OpenGL?  Table views?  Another big issue I've run into is that if you want to do a fresh install on the simulator, you have to fully delete it off of the simulator's home screen, as build-and-run sometimes won't get everything.  (This is just like on the device but it can be easy to forget the Simulator needs it too.)

Comment: The problem I have is that a CALayer is only refreshing a limited number of times (like 3 or 4) on my iPad, but in simulator it refreshes any number of times I want. I'm working on an app that uses a custom video player (AVFoundation) that has to play multiple videos on demand, in simulator it works perfectly, but not on my iPad.

Comment: Do you mean it's getting 3-4 fps, or it's only refreshing 3-4 times and then dies?  One thing to consider is that if you have a method called on a timer, and that method expects the *previous* call to be complete, it would work on the Mac due to the better performance but on the iPad it might be catching up to itself too fast.  Do you have a timer you can throttle?

Comment: No, the app mechanics are as follows: I have a certain number of video files on my device's documents folder, when the app it searches all those video files and stores and indexes them in a plist. Then I start the player with the first file as default and it starts playing it. If the user makes a swipe gesture the player plays the next video file, and waits for the next swipe, and so on. In the simulator, I can do this indefinitely, the player always plays the next items. On my iPad, after 3 or 4 swipes, the player view just goes blank, and there is no way to make it display anything again.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to **debug** in exactly the same way on the device - it will handle breakpoints, work with instruments, give console output, etc. As others have pointed out, trying to predict when the device and simulator will vary in behavior is very difficult. So you should definitely rely more on the device as a debugging tool. The major difference that keeps cropping up is processor speed - the simulator can handle much more intense tasks than the device can. Debug on the device whenever possible.