# Using ATPagingView(ScrollView) to display multiple pages, but some show as blank if I go out and come back in

Tags: ios, ios4, avfoundation, avplayer

So I set up an ATPagingView(ScrollView)(https://github.com/andreyvit/SoloComponents-iOS/tree/master/ATPagingView) with a custom PageView for each page. The page view is loaded with a AVPlayerLayer which was/is loaded with a AVPlayer(was because as part of trying to fix this I have tried using an AVQueuePlayer). Now the ATPagingView had page recycling built in so that I shouldn't be loading all 15 video at once(have it set to 3) and I added a reload function to the PageView that basically loads the video for the new page index without re-initing everything, but before I just re-inited everything and it still didn't work. I'm pretty positive it's a memory thing with the avplayers, but the profiler shows no leaks and a constant memory footprint. I now that the ATPagingView is sending the right index and everything because I also have labels on the PageViews that are correct.

I have tried this: [Playing many different videos on iphone using AVPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258573/playing-many-different-videos-on-iphone-using-avplayer) with no luck. As well as trying to use AVQueuePlayers to handle the reloading instead of replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:. Again no luck.

Here is roughly the init code now:

```
    NSURL* m =[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:page.video withExtension:page.videoExt];


        self.player = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:m]]];
        self.playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];

        self.playerLayer.frame = self.frame;
        [img.layer addSublayer: self.playerLayer];
        self.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone; 

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                     name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                   object:[self.player currentItem]];
        [self.player play];
```

And the reload code looks something like this:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[self.player currentItem]];
[self.player removeAllItems];

        NSURL* m =[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:page.video withExtension:page.videoExt];

        //AVPlayer version
        url = m;
        AVAsset *newAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
        AVPlayerItem *newPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:newAsset];
        [self.player insertItem:newPlayerItem afterItem:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:newPlayerItem];
        [self.player play];
```

Like I said, it's not everytime it reloads, but if I go into the ATPagingView and then exit it back to the menu and then go back in that's when it'll start happening.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the loader to not pre-cache the views and it fixed it! Released on the market now^^

Answer (score 0):

While that fixed that app, the new one I'm working on it is almost necessary that I have multiple player controllers. I am using a block for the load of the asset(confirming that the asset is loaded) and observer for the ReadyToPlay status on the player. Also, I have it making sure that the avplayerlayer's superlayer isn't nil and that it was the last playerlayer loaded on that view. It's rarer after all of this and having the app reload these with new media whenever possible(again using the blocks and observer), but there are still times when I'll switch to a playercontroller and it'll have a blank space where the movie should be. (reports the asset as loaded and the avplayerlayer as haven't a superlayer and the meta-data for the movie is correct). Really lost on this one. Any Ideas?!

Thanks,
-Matt