# Playing interactive videos with finger gestures in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am working on a kids ABC learning app which will be somewhat like this app.
[Petting Zoo](https://youtube.com/watch?v=3MUi3QGaJMo)

The user can do these gestures... Swipe UP, DOWN, LEFT , RIGHT and TOUCH and each gesture has a small animation clip (approx duration 1 -3 secs each ) linked to it like the character jumping on Swipe UP, etc. There will also be an IDLE loopable movie which will be playing continuously when there is no input from user.

So I am trying to use videos in MP4 and M4V format for these gestures but the problem is that the videos are lagging just before playing. Means they dont play instantly upon doing a gesture but take a time of say micro second to load and play.

I am looking for output like the video above. You can see that the animations are so responsive and do not hang even for little time.

My developer once achieved such smooth output with the MP4 video clips but those clips didnt have audio embedded in them and then when he used videos with audio embedded in them, they were lagging again.

Can audio be the issue for lag here ? Or anything else you experts will like to suggest.

Please help guys. Yours inputs will be very valuable for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `- (void)replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:(AVPlayerItem *)item` of AVPlayer.

This methods helps you to load the new item to an existing AVPlayer.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258573/playing-many-different-videos-on-iphone-using-avplayer) is the important reference for playing multiple videos using single AVPlayer.

Comment: Hi Pradeep.. thanks a lot for replying... I have shared  this link with my developer.. lets see what he comes up with...

Comment: Using multiple AVPlayer for playing videos does results in delay, try to use single AVPlayer with multiple assets :)