# Playing an AVAsset while simultaneously adding other assets to end of video

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video-streaming, avfoundation

I'm aware of how to merge videos together using an AVMutableComposition (lots of good posts on this. See https://github.com/ChrisGrant/AVFoundation-Video-Stitching for example)

But is there any way to play an asset that is currently being merged together. Something like one thread plays the video while another is actively merging new assets to the end?

I want to be able to pull multiple assets from a server and merge them into an uninterrupted viewing experience (feed? Similar to Snapchat I guess) without the user having to wait for all of them to load or having to potentially worry about memory issues.

Ive been looking at documentation but can't seem to find a solution. Appreciate any input, thanks.

Comment: If you are not actually merging the videos then, you have to have mutiple AVAssets (Array of AVAssets), and then once a AVAssetItem gets to the end, change the current item of the AVPlayer using replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem method. This link might come in handy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258573/playing-many-different-videos-on-iphone-using-avplayer

Comment: Have you looked at AVQueuePlayer?